# Game on a number line

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Define a game on a number line as follows: at the beginning, there are (possibly) some tokens at some negative integers on the number line. Each integer can hold any number of tokens. At each step, before you move a token to an adjacent integer, an adjacent token (not at the same integer) must be $\color{red}{\text{removed}}$ as a cost. If you can let a token reside at some integer after a finite number of moves, it is said that the integer is "reachable". Your goal is to obtain the maximum "reachable" integer.

For example, suppose there are two tokens at $-2$ and three tokens at $-1$. Via the following moves, you can reach the integer $2$:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{integers} & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{\textrm{2}} \\ \hline
\text{beginning} & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{after move } 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{after move } 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{after move } 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\text{after move } 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
In the table, the first row means the integers while each of the following row represents the tokens after a move. We can see that the maximum reachable integer is $2$.

I'd like to ask, given an initial distribution of tokens, how to calculate the maximum reachable integer? An analysis on simple cases (for example, there are tokens on integers $-1$ and $-2$ only) are also appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @BadAtGeometry understandable question, but I am just putting [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic) out there so we all know...

Comment: @user477343 Oh thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the one-dimensional version of the (cool and interesting!) two-dimensional ["Conway's soldiers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers) problem. In particular, you're essentially replacing a pair of tokens on spaces $n-2$ and $n-1$ with a token on space $n$, which means that assigning weight $\phi^n$ to space $n$ (where $\phi$ is the golden ratio) is preserved by this token move. In your example, the initial weighted sum of tokens is
$$
2\cdot\phi^{-2}+3\cdot\phi^{-1} = \frac{3+\sqrt5}2 = \phi^2,
$$
which is a proof that no integer greater than $2$ is reachable for this example.

Comment: Yes, two games are identical in one-dimensional case. But in the two-dimensional extension, this game seems different from Conway's game due to different "remove" rule. May I ask how to analyze this game in two-dimensional extension?

Comment: @HangWu, Can you help me this problem:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213078/two-players-choosing-one-of-three-numbers