# Two players choosing one of three numbers

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

> $A$ and $B$ play the following game. Initially, for positive integer $n$, each player takes turns choosing one of three numbers:
>
> - $1$
> - the number of digits of $n$
> - the sum of the digits of $n$.
>
> and then updates the number $n$ by subtracting the number selected. If $n$ becomes $0$, the person who has that turn wins. Who will be the winner if $A$ is always the first to go?

For example:

- With $n=3$, the result is $A$, because $A$ chooses the number that is the sum of the digits of $n = 3$, after selecting, $n$ is updated and becomes $0$. So $A$ wins.
- With $n=10$, the result is $B$, because $A$ can only choose $1$ or $2$ (because the number of digits of $10$ is $2$ and the sum of the digits of $10$ is $1$). So, when choosing, $n$ can only be $8$ or $9$. Next $B$ selects $8$ or $9$ and wins.

My problem is to determine who the winner is when $n$ is known.

Comment: And how far have you gotten with it?

Comment: I think, every turn A will try to get maximize of three number, after that I can't think more!!!. @saulspatz

Comment: Try figuring out who wins if the the number is $11,12,13,\dots$ and see if can find a pattern.

Comment: After trying with $n=11,12,13$, I see that A always wins!!!. And I think the result of this problem is A always win when $n\ne 10$ and B always wins when $n=10$. @saulspatz, but I thinks I am wrong!!

Comment: If the number is $13$, A loses.  Also, three examples are nowhere near enough.  Actually, I don't see a pattern here.  Are you supposed to find a formula or write a computer program?

Comment: I write a computer a program @saulspatz

Comment: I try find a formula for this problem to write a compute program, but it's not succesful! @saulspatz

Comment: I don't see a formula either.  It seems very erratic.

Comment: I think this problem may be relevant to recursion and the base is with $n<10$, we always determine who is the winner!!!  @saulspatz

Comment: @saulspatz , I see that if $n>=10$ and $n\equiv 1(\text{ mod }3)$ then $B$ wins.

Comment: I wonder whether it would be easier to analyze the problem for base 2, and then see how to generalize the analysis so it works for base 10.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330743/two-players-choosing-one-of-three-numbers with no notice to either site. THAT'S AN ABUSE!

Comment: Can you give me clearly solution!!! I can't think problem for base 2! @GerryMyerson

Comment: No, I can't give you "clearly solution", and I wouldn't if I could, you rude, abusive person. Please clean up your act.

Comment: So, I try to find who is winner with $n=10,11,12,...$ and I see that with $n>10$ and $n\equiv 1(\text{ mod }3)$, the result is B!!!

Comment: I noticed that pattern too, but it doesn't persist; try some larger numbers.  When $n=151$, A wins.

Comment: I have got accepted this problem. I try build recusive form, you can see it here: https://ideone.com/tZWljX